# JavaScript Interval error

Tags: javascript, intervals

Can anyone tell me why this code doesn't work. I just want the images to change after a set time. It works when i am using a button.[You can see the image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdwDP.png)

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code as an image but rather as code-formatted text. For more on this, please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/522444).

Comment: For instance, if we want to test and modify your code, then your posting it as an image will force us to type it all in, whereas if it were code-formatted text, we could just copy and paste it into our IDE. Why make the volunteers here do extra work to provide you with free help?

Answer (score 2):

You need to update from

```
setInterval(changeLights(), 2000);
```

to

```
setInterval(changeLights, 2000);
```